# Why can LocalDateTime return the instance?

Tags: java, java-8, abstract-class, abstract, java-time

[LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is *abstract* class. So I cannot write:

```
LocalDateTime value = new LocalDateTime(); //error
```

If I want to get its instance, I have to write:

```
LocalDateTime value = LocalDateTime.now(); //not error
```

I have a question, **Why can LocalDateTime return the instance?** It's an abstract class.

I saw the overview, but I could not find it...

Comment: To understand more about this, learn about [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) being used instead of `new`, and about [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` is **not** an abstract class.

```
public final class LocalDateTime
    implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, ChronoLocalDateTime<LocalDate>, Serializable {
```

It has private constructors, so direct instantiation is not possible. Factory method such `now()`, `now(ZoneId)` etc are used to create instances.

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime is an immutable date-time object that represents a date-time.

This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

Hence it has static methods e.g.

```
LocalDateTime desc = LocalDateTime.now();
```